# Programmatically get semi-public facebook info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

I'm beating my head against a brick wall. I need to find user information which has been set as public.

I have an Fb application which the user has to approve before this process takes place so this isn't invasive.

I've got a test user profile up here: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100003207005980

If you browse to it while not logged in to FB, you don't see some information even if it's flagged as "public" eg email address. (Hence semi-public in the title)

I can "fake" an Fb login as a different user using CURL but it doesn't help me as the page contents are all loaded dynamically using JS. In addition, key details are obscured by Fb dumping odd tags/line breaks in. This makes string matching impossible in the time I have to hand and it would be really fragile.

If I use the graph API, I get all the users details but no indication of if they're shared or not. The same is true of the FBQL - at least I haven't found a way to limit either to include only the public info.

Using email address as an example, how can I determine if the email address I have on record is being exposed by the user through facebook to members of the public?